# Unable to redirect to DropBox login page

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, dropbox

I am integrating DropBox in my Java based application. The following piece of code, when executed in stand alone mode, works fine.

```
private String APP_KEY = "APP_KEY";
private String APP_SECRET = "APP_SECRET";
private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
WebAuthSession session = new WebAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);


WebAuthInfo authInfo = session.getAuthInfo("callbackURL");

RequestTokenPair pair = authInfo.requestTokenPair;
String url = authInfo.url;
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URL(url).toURI());
session.retrieveWebAccessToken(pair);

AccessTokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
```

In stand alone mode this piece of code redirects me to the DropBox log-in page, the user will authorize the app and then the control is back on to the page mentioned in the "callbackURL".

I use the same patch when i am actually running my site. I have a link saying "Link to DropBox now." On clicking the link, the control is passed to the server via a REST call to execute the above code. But it gets stuck at the line of code which says,

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URL(url).toURI());
```

when all the parameters required to get the **authInfo()** are properly passed.

I am not able to determine where i am going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "I use the same patch when i am actually running my site." and "Desktop.getDesktop()" ? Are you invoking this piece of code from a Desktop-application or a Web-application (i.e. a servlet) ?

Comment: From a web application. I tried to find if there was any change i needed to do in the above statement for Java, but with less help.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot call `Desktop.getDesktop()` in the context of a web-app (at beast you would be referring to the servers own desktop). How about redirecting the user (something like: `response.sendRedirect("callbackURL");`) ?

Comment: Okay. I will try that and will let you know.

Comment: Have you done any progress with that ? If you were able to solve your problem, please consider posting the answer and marking it as "accepted", so people facing a similar problem in the future will be able to easily find the solution. (In case you are still looking for a solution, let us know about your attempts and results and maybe someone will be able to provide useful advice.)

Comment: Actually since i am running a web app, i cannot use Desktop.getDesktop() as you rightly mentioned. So i have to redirect using javascript. I am still over it and tried using window.location, but in vain. I pass the url i receive in the statement **authInfo.url** to the front end, and then set it to window.location, but it didnt work. So yes, still looking for the answer.

Comment: Have you tried setting `window.location.href` ? If it doesn't work, give more details about how it fails.

Comment: I atleast got the redirection logic. I used jquery. I set the url to **href** attribute of **a** tag and it did work. Now i am figuring out how to get the Access tokens in the front end after the user authorizes the app to access the users dropbox on behalf of the user.

Comment: Why get the access_token in the front-end ? That should happen in the back-end. You specify a callback URL and there you have a servlet parsing Dropbpx's response from [this step](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#authorize) (see the "RETURNS" section and then perform [that step](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#access-token) and retrieving the access_token (and orobably storing it somewhere along with the rest necessary data).

Comment: Will get back to you after doing it.

Comment: You are right. It had to be done the way you told. Thanks for your help. It is better if you can post the answer so that i will accept, anyways after all you earn it.

Comment: Glad you did it ! I did post an answer for you to accept. (Appreciated ;)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your is a web-application you cannot call `Desktop.getDesktop()` (which is meaningful only in the context of a desktop-application).

You should redirect the user to Dropbox (namely to the URL you receive in the statement `authInfo.url`), using something like `response.sendRedirect("callbackURL");` or using JavaScript on the client-side to set the `href` of a link.

Then, Dropbox will redirect the user back to your app (namely to the URL you specified as "callbackURL"), where you should have a servlet parse Dropbox's response (**[more info here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#authorize)** - take a look at the "RETURNS" section) and then acquire the _access_token_ (**[as described here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#access-token)**).
(At that point you would probably want to store it somewhere (e.g. in the session-scope) along with the rest of the necessary data.)